# Conversion from IplImage* to cv::MAT

Tags: c++, opencv, iplimage, mat

I searched to convert an IplImage* to Mat, but all answers were about the conversion to cvMat.

How, can I do it? and what is the difference between Mat and cvMat?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regarding cvMat and Mat , see the link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037798/difference-between-cvmat-mat-and-ipimage

Answer (score 14, accepted):

here is a good solution

```
Mat(const IplImage* img, bool copyData=false);
```

Comment: afaik newer OpenCV versions (3.x) don't support this constructor anymore.

Comment: It has been a long time so :)

Comment: a curent question was linked to this answer, so I just wanted to mention that :)

Comment: @Micka For OpenCV 3.x you can use cv::cvarrToMat(ipl*). Below answer was answered this issue :)

Answer (score 45):

For the records: taking a look at core/src/matrix.cpp it seems that, indeed, the constructor `cv::Mat(IplImage*)` has disappeared.

But I found this alternative:

```
IplImage * ipl = ...;
cv::Mat m = cv::cvarrToMat(ipl);  // default additional arguments: don't copy data.
```

Comment: Original [source](https://answers.opencv.org/question/23440/any-way-to-convert-iplimage-to-cvmat-in-opencv-300/) for this answer...

Answer (score 11):

The recommended way is the [`cv::cvarrToMat`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cvarrtomat) function

`cv::Mat` - is base data structure for OpenCV 2.x

`CvMat` - is old C analog of `cv::Mat`

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [Mat documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat).

```
// converts old-style IplImage to the new matrix; the data is not copied by default
Mat(const IplImage* img, bool copyData=false);
```

Comment: This constructor will be completely removed from the API in the next major update of the library

Comment: @AndreyKamaev Are you sure about this? Shouldn't this constructor be marked as deprecated then?

Answer (score 4):

- cv::Mat or Mat, both are same.
- Mat has a operator CvMat() so simple assignment works

**Convert Mat to CvMat**

```
Mat mat = ---------;
CvMat cvmat = mat;
```

**Convert CVMat to Mat**

```
Mat dst = Mat(cvmat, true);
```

**Convert Mat to IplImage***

**> For Single Channel**

```
IplImage* image = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)mat);
```

**> For Three Channel**

```
IplImage* image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(mat.cols, mat.rows), 8, 3);
IplImage ipltemp = mat;
cvCopy(&ipltemp, image);
```

Hope this helps you. Cheers :)