# Reading and processing images (opencv/c++)

Tags: c++

My project is recognizing faces from images. The images have the same name and change occasionally
So i want to load and process the images every time they change
how can i modify this:

```
    while (image==NULL) {
    image = cvLoadImage("ayman.jpg", 1);
}
cout << endl << "My image was finally loaded!";
```

sorry for my english

Comment: Which OS? In linux you could use inotify.

Comment: Could you describe it specifically with an example ?

Comment: Use inotify. You can add a watch on a file and get an event every time the file changes.

Comment: @RafaFirenze the images came from another processing: detecting only adult people. then i cut the human body and save it. this work every time the cam detect an adult so the image change every time a new human appear. so i want to load this image and recognize it

Comment: does the name of the image changes as well ?

Comment: @RafaFirenze no the name doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's assume than your images are different at the moment they change (random). How do we detect that it's another image, different from the previous one?

We are going to extract 3 features of your image and it is: the mean of the RED CHANNEL, GREEN CHANNEL and BLUE CHANNEL (it's a vector). So, if the image is the same, the 3 means are the same, but if it's different, the image has been changed.

So think we are in a infinite loop (your `while`).

```
while(true) {
    // we are going to say here if the image has changed or not
}
```

Are we ok ? So this is the code:

```
    image = cvLoadImage("ayman.jpg", 1);
    Scalar meanOfImage = mean(image);

    while (true) {
        Scalar meanAtThisMoment = mean(image);
        // This are the three features (it's in real one, but one vector of 3).
        // We are going to compare the three to be more clear.
        if (meanAtThisMoment[0] == meanOfImage[0]
            &&
            meanAtThisMoment[1] == meanOfImage[1]
            &&
            meanAtThisMoment[2] == meanOfImage[2]) {

            cout << endl << "The image hasn't been changed yet.";
            image = cvLoadImage("ayman.jpg", 1); // added!! forgot this, sorry
        } else {

            cout << endl << "The image has been changed!!!";
            // and now we set the meanOfImage (the main mean) of the new image to compare with the future images.

            meanOfImage = meanAtThisMoment;



        }

    }
```

Comment: sorry mate, I forgot to add one line!!! I commented as " // added!! forgot this, sorry "... please try and tell me if it worked ;)

Comment: thanks Rafa  i changed the image but the Xterm keep telling me that "The image hasn't been changed yet."

Comment: consider to remove the first cout (the sentence: `cout << endl << "The image hasn't been changed yet."` and so you will get notified ONLY when it's been changed ;). If it was ok you can accept it as correct answer :)

Comment: the image change only if i close the image window but thats ok!! thank you :)

Comment: I guess the image changes in the memory when you close it, that's why. Try to save it with the same name, it will change as well :).

Comment: sorry for disturbing Rafa but this is functional only with Mat images . my input images are iplimage* . any idea for this ? (i'm a electrical engineer student not a programmer :/ )

Comment: I would highly reccommend you to use Mat since `IplImage` is used in older versions. If still it doesn't work, you can convert from IplImage to Mat, for example by this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925084/conversion-from-iplimage-to-cvmat

Comment: i found another solution :
AFTER THIS:                  
while (image==NULL) {
    image = cvLoadImage("ayman.jpg", 1);
}
cout << endl << "My image was finally loaded!";                                   
I ADDED                      
while(!image.empty()){
image= cvLoadImage("css.jpg", 1);                                
thats worked perfectly :D