# OpenCV - How to write IplImage array in Mat form?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, iplimage

My old project was wrote in C, which includes lots of "IplImage".

Here is one example,

```
IplImage** img_array = new IplImage* [img_number];
for(int i = 0; i < img_number; i++)
{
    img_array[i] = cvCreateImage(cvSize(320, 240), IPl_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    cvSet(img_array[i], cvScalar(0, 0, 0));
}
.
.
.
.
.
for(int i = 0; i < img_number; i++)
{
    cvReleaseImage(&img_array[i]);
}
delete[] img_array;
```

Now I have to rewrite my project into C++ form, which I should use cv::Mat.

However, I am not sure the equal way to write my code above into cv::Mat?

I tried write in this way:

```
int dims[] = {img_number, 320, 240};
cv::Mat img_array(3, dims, CV_8UC3);
```

everything seems good though, but when comes to a line:

```
for(int i = 0; i < img_number; i++)
{
    img_array[i] = random_img.clone();
}
```

an error showup:

```
C2676:binary operator'[':'cv::Mat'does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

After that I found another way that might possibly do, but requires using vector:

```
vector<Mat> img_array;
for(int i = 0 ; i < img_number; i++)
{
    img_array.push_back(random_img.clone());
}
```

I haven't implement yet, I am not sure whether this is the solution I want?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: definitely use `vector<Mat>`!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should view `cv::Mat` class as a replacement for old `IplImage*`. The constructor you were using is supposed to create a multidimensional `cv::Mat` instance, which is probably not what you were looking for. According to your `IplImage*` based code you were probably trying to create a set of Mat images from a set of `IplImage` pointers . For that this ctor will serve better:

```
Mat::Mat(const IplImage* img, bool copyData=false)
```

If you set `copyData` argument to *true*, the constructor will copy the contents of IplImage* and control the new data buffer as usual (reference counting, proper deallocation etc.) If you set it to false, the original IplImage* data will be used and you must take care not to free it before you are done with your cv::Mat instance.

The original docs are [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)

And, yes, generally it is better to place your cv::Mat instances into a vector. In this case the memory used by `Mat`s will be automatically freed when the vector goes out of scope (unless you have created some other `cv::Mat`s which reference the original data, but that's another story)

**Edit**
It appears that the Mat constructor above is not recommended to use. You should use `cvarrToMat()` function instead, as suggested in answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925084/conversion-from-iplimage-to-cvmat) question

Comment: Thanks for your advice