# How to convert an image into a matrix in opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, matrix

As it is said in the title, i want to convert an image into a matrix to be able to do some calculation i have used this declaration but it show me an error :  no matching function for call to c::Mat::Mat(IplImage*&)

```
IplImage* image1 = cvLoadImage("C://images//PolarImage300915163358.bmp", 1);
Mat mtx(image1); // convert IplImage* -> Mat
```

is there something wrong with this declaration

Comment: Don't mix C and C++ interfaces. `IplImage` is outdated, as it is `cvLoadImage`. Use instead `cv::imread`. [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html) you find a tutorial. Note: `cv::Mat` is already the preferred OpenCV image format.

Comment: also you could have tried this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30849778/888688), but as @Antonio said, the c++ interface is preferred, specially if your final goal is to get a `cv::Mat`.

Answer (score -1):

It worked with this declaration

```
Mat   image1 = imread("C://images//PolarImage300915163358.bmp");
```