Win32 API convert ID3D11Texture2D to cv::Mat
So I am trying to convert ID3D11Texture2D to OpenCV cv::Mat, but my code distorts the image for some reason.
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC capturedTextureDesc;
texture->GetDesc(&capturedTextureDesc);
capturedTextureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
capturedTextureDesc.BindFlags = 0;
capturedTextureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
capturedTextureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

winrt::com_ptr<ID3D11Texture2D> userTexture = nullptr;
winrt::check_hresult(d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&capturedTextureDesc, NULL, userTexture.put()));
d3dContext->CopyResource(userTexture.get(), texture.get());
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE resource;
winrt::check_hresult(d3dContext->Map(userTexture.get(), NULL, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &resource));

//https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.02514
int scWidth = capturedTextureDesc.Width;
int scHeight = capturedTextureDesc.Height;
int CAMERA_CHANNELS = 4;
unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[(scWidth * scHeight * CAMERA_CHANNELS)];
unsigned char* mappedData = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(resource.pData);
memcpy(buffer, mappedData, (scWidth * scHeight * CAMERA_CHANNELS));
d3dContext->Unmap(userTexture.get(), 0);
IplImage* frame = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(scWidth, scHeight),
    IPL_DEPTH_8U, CAMERA_CHANNELS);
frame->imageData = (char*)buffer;
cvSetData(frame, buffer, frame->widthStep);
// cv::Mat mt = cv::Mat(frame, true); // constructor dissapered
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925084/conversion-from-iplimage-to-cvmat
cv::Mat mt = cv::cvarrToMat(frame);
return mt;

Here is the window captured with the cv::Mat output:

They have the same size , but the content is different.

cvSetData(frame, buffer, frame->widthStep) should use the step (AKA stride / pitch) of the original DX texture.

How do i get the step from the original texture?

Added an answer with this info. Also see there why there's no need to using IplImage in order to finally get a cv::Mat.

The code doesn't seem to be referencing the RowPitch value in the D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE.  RowPitch is not always width*pixelSize - each row can be buffered such that the row width is a multiple of 16 or some other value.
Instead of this:
memcpy(buffer, mappedData, (scWidth * scHeight * CAMERA_CHANNELS));

Copy row by row:
for (int h = 0; h < scHeight; h++) {
    unsigned char* srcRow = mappedData + (resource.RowPitch * h);
    unsigned char* dstRow = buffer + scWidth * CAMERA_CHANNELS * h;
    memcpy(dstRow, srcRow, scWidth*CAMERA_CHANNELS);
}

Or.... pass the rowPitch to OpenCV.
buffer = new unsigned char[resource.RowPitch * scHeight * CAMERA_CHANNELS];
memcpy(buffer, mappedData, resource.RowPitch * scHeight * CAMERA_CHANNELS);

...

cvSetData(frame, buffer, resource.RowPitch);


Call MFCopyImage instead of the copy loop, will be faster.

@Soonts - I can double check, but I am fairly certain memcpy on latest Visual C++ has the same SSE/SSE2 optimizations that MFCopyImage does.  In some controlled test apps compiled with optimizations on, I think I see SSE/SSE2 instructions when I step through the assembly.

The problem is related to invalid stride (AKA step / pitch).
The stride is the number of bytes in an image row.
It can be indeed scWidth * CAMERA_CHANNELS but it doesn't have to.
Sometimes (due to alignement issues) each row is padded with some bytes.
In your code you assume there's no such padding, but according to the image you posted there actually is.
The solution is to use the stride from the DirectX texture - i.e. resource.rowPitch (instead of assuming it is scWidth * CAMERA_CHANNELS).
Another issue is that you don't have to use IplImage in an intermediate stage. Since you want a cv::Mat, you can use it directly. You don't even need buffer - you can initialize the cv::Mat directly from the mapped data:
unsigned char* mappedData = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(resource.pData);
cv::Mat mt = cv::Mat(scHeight, scWidth, CV_8UC4, mappedData, resource.rowPitch).clone();
d3dContext->Unmap(userTexture.get(), 0);
return mt;

Note: clone() is used because thecv::Mat constrcutor that accepts data and stride creates a cv::Mat that does not own the data. clone() creates a copy that does own it.
