# OpenCVSharp 2: FloodFill is broken and corrupts output mask

Tags: c#, opencv, mat

Using latest v2 of OpenCVSharp (2.4.10.201...), which I installed in my project with the NuGet manager.

It seems the floodfill function has a memory-corruption issue. I am applying it to the following image:
[image]

and here is the result:
[image]

while the mask produced follows the same corruption pattern:
[image]

The code I use is:

```
filledArea = new CvMat( hue.Rows + 2, hue.Cols + 2, MatrixType.U8C1 );
Cv.FloodFill( hue, hintPos, new CvScalar(255,255,255), low, upp, out filledAreaData,
    FloodFillFlag.Link8 | FloodFillFlag.FixedRange, filledArea );
```

where
***hue*** is the input image

***hintPos*** is CvPoint(10,400)

***low = upp*** = CvScalar(10,10,10,10)

***Note***: the "corruption pattern" is random and changes every time.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with not initializing the mask with zero values. It looks like this:

```
filledArea = new CvMat( hue.Rows + 2, hue.Cols + 2, MatrixType.U8C1 );
```

DOESN'T initialize the reserved memory to ANY value, so you get "corrupted" pixels.

```
filledArea = new CvMat( hue.Rows + 2, hue.Cols + 2, MatrixType.U8C1, new CvScalar(0,0,0,0) );
```

DOES create a mask with 0 pixels.

My wrong, I thought it wasn't possible in C# to grab new memory without first initializing it to some value, as is the case with Array[] and List...

Comment: OpenCvSharp wraps OpenCV which is written in C++ and C. OpenCvSharp `Mat` uses mostly unmanaged memory.

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev Yes, but this isn't Mat I was using. It's the C# equivalent CvMat..?

Comment: `CvMat` and `Mat` are pretty much same things both in OpenCV and it's managed wrapper OpenCvSharp. Check [Difference between cvMat, Mat and IpImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037798/difference-between-cvmat-mat-and-ipimage), [Mat versus CvMat](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/95) discussions and `Mat` OpenCvSharp [source code](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/bfaf35f385fd5eda49792dfd19db27bcef079f9f/src/OpenCvSharp/modules/core/Mat/Mat.cs#L47) (note `NativeMethods` class usage).